# htaccess redirect removing special chars

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I want to redirect this URL `http://www.domain.com/forum/1122554-lorem-ipsum-u-dolor%C4%8Dsimit-lorem` into `http://www.domain.com/forum/1122554-lorem-ipsum-u-dolorsimit-lorem`

I tried:

```
%C4%8D == č
RewriteRule ^forum/(.+)(č)(.+) /forum/$1$3 [R=301,L]
this also not worked
RewriteRule ^forum/(.+)(%C4%8D)(.+) /forum/$1$3 [R=301,L]
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^forum/(.*)([^a-zA-Z0-9-./]+)(.*) /forum/$1$3 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the Correct Answer, Sorry Guys, I have figure out myself! I hope this will help other s as well!
    ^/forum/(.*)(?:%C4%8D|č) /forum/$1